# Where to place the SaveChanges method when using EF with service and/or repositories?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the entity framework invoked directly from the controller.

I am working on structuring the project by creating services.

For example: CustomerService, ProductService.

At this point I can inject entity framework into the above services or create generic/concrete repositories and inject entity framework into the repositories, and inject the repostories into respective services.

In both the above scenarios I want to understand where do I place the SaveaChanges call? That is:

1. Within the service as a method?
2. Within each create/update/delete method in the service?
3. Within the repository as a method?
4. Within each create/update/delete method in the repository?

What is the basis on which to arrive at a decision as to where to place the SaveChanges?

Comment: What about [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#implement-a-generic-repository-and-a-unit-of-work-class)

Comment: One method is using `SaveChanges` in filter in your Api project. I think write `SaveChanges` into each method in service is a little bit cumbersome. You can custom an attribute and receive dbcontext as property. Then in filter you can use reflection to get the action which used your custom attribute, Then do `SaveChanges` method to these action. Now in controller, You can just add your custom attribute to these actions which you want use `savechange` method.